# Get input parameter from specific onclick function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like if it's posible to the input parameter from specific function. Example:

```
<div onclick="function1('value1')"></div>
<div onclick="function1('value2')"></div>
<div onclick="function2('value1')"></div>
<div onclick="function2('value2')"></div>
```

As you can see in this example i would like to get input parameters from function1.

Is this posible?

Comment: Please post function1 and function2 as well.  As it stands this code will just cause errors.

Comment: You have error.

Comment: @Archer Is not about the function, i want to know if i can get all DOM elements that got function1 and then get his value1 input. This is an example i know it's not actually running

Comment: In that case, please create a **[mcve]** to demonstrate what you have and explain what you are trying to achieve.  The question is currently unclear.

Comment: It'll probably be better to just put a class, id or data-attribute on the <div>s that you want to select. Once you start replacing `onclick="someFunctionName"` with `.addEventListener('click',someFunctionName);`, you won't be able to use the selector looking for function1() . So I would go for `<div data-value="value1"></div>` so that you can use `div[data-value]` as a selector for all those DOM elements, completely independent from how function1() and function2() work. Function1() can then also use the data-value attribute of the clicked nodes.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this. 
Example:

```
<button onclick="myFunction('raman')">Click me</button>

<script>
function myFunction(a) {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = a;
}
</script>
```